# Is SQLite sufficient for my case?

Tags: sqlite

I am writing a simple program with 2 windows. In the first window the user selects a number from 1-10, he does that for lets say 1 month.
In the second window, I have a graph showing this numbers increase or decrease in a period (1 month).

Can I use SQLite for saving this data?

As far as i understand SQLite is a local database where you don't need internet access (The intended users don't have access to the internet.).
What happens if the user shuts down his phone? I.e. is that data still stored on the phone (any time frame how long this data is saved)?
Any ideas of where to save data? Or is SQLite the answer here?

Comment: yes sqlite is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite uses a file on storage medium (e.g. hard disk). So the data are safe while the file exists.

Your description seems to indicate one frequent access displaying and one much less frequent access writing. You might have designed two separate processes. For that case let me mention that using SQLite from two programs/processes/users can give you problems; the same kind of problems as you might get when trying to access any other kind of file from two programs/processes/users at the same time.

In my experience, writing from a single "side" and reading from one or more other "sides" is mostly not a problem. This seems to fit your described circumstances.